# mysql tables moved all views are gone

Tags: mysql, view, phpmyadmin

I had a website with database and all and I recently imported all tables to different database.  I had multiple views with queries all in working order.  Now that I imported it...all my views seem to be gone and have changed to regular tables which interferes with my queries.  Is this normal and if so...how could I either fix it easily without having to redo every view...or re-import the database leaving the views as they should.
I am using phpmyadmin and all queries are mysql.  I'm sorry if not enough information I'll gladly post more if needed.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Only thing I can think of causing the view's being gone is that the database prefix is obviously different...

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the error: #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation 


This is stopping my views from being populated, but I don't know how to fix this. I've changed all entries in my .sql file to reflect the new user but nothing changed.